# Stop console printing the same message multiple times when inputting an string instead of integer

Tags: go, console

In my CLI program I have this functionality where a user can tell me how many items of a certain product they want. Therefore this input is expected to be an integer.

I'm currently having an issue where if they input a string it will error saying it `expected an integer` but then also print the question again multiple times instead of just once.

Example:

```
How many Fruit Tea would you like to buy? qwe
expected integer
How many Fruit Tea would you like to buy? expected integer
How many Fruit Tea would you like to buy? expected integer
How many Fruit Tea would you like to buy?
```

Below is the code that handles this functionality

```
for {
    fmt.Printf("How many %v would you like to buy? ", product.Name)
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&response)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    if ok, err := validResponse(response); ok {
        break
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }
}
```

What do I have to change in this loop so it only repeats the question once?

Comment: Just move the initial question outside the for loop

Comment: @Vasanth the issue with this is once they enter a string of text instead of an integer it prints the error but then doesn't repeat the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, switch the type of `response` from `int` to `string` then parse the input string using package `strconv` (such as `strconv.Atoi()` ). I suspect `Scan` is trying to read each character you entered as a separate int, failing each time, and running the loop each time until all the characters have been consumed.

for example

```
    for {
        var response string
        fmt.Printf("How many %v would you like to buy? ", product.Name)
        _, err := fmt.Scanln(&response)
        if err != nil { // probably don't need to check err from Scan()
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        num, err := strconv.Atoi(response)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Enter an integer.")
            continue
        }

        if ok, err := validResponse(num); ok && err==nil {
            break
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that works. I did think of this method but thought maybe there was a simpler way. Seems not! Thanks for the help :)